# Exclude suppressed fields from Sum

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I need your help in excluding the suppressed amounts from the SUM in the group footer. In the details section, I am having duplicate deal no and amounts.So, in the Section Expert for the details sections, I performed a condition on the formula "Suppress" to suppress the duplicated fields which is:

{deal_no} = (next{deal_no})

The above condition is applied in the report and I was able to suppress the duplicates. Now in the group footer, I am performing a running total using the formulas to calculate the SUM for the amounts. However, this SUM is calculating the suppressed amounts and it is giving the results. So how to remove them from the calculation.

Comment: can you explain your running total condition how did you apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
If {deal_no} <> (next{deal_no}) OR OnLastRecord then //this excludes the duplicates
(
numbervar gsum := gsum + {@Cost};
numbervar grand := grand + gsum;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is instead of using `running total` you can just summarize by right clicking on the field and using `Insert Summary` which will give correct result.

Comment: I am having a formula which is called Cost. In this formula I am having an if statement as below if group = "TERMS" Then 0 else {Table A.Amount} * 100/{@no.ofdays} . Here I can't use a summary

Comment: Why can't you use summary? have you went to insert summary and checked whether you cans ee the option or not.. To the extent I know since you are manipulatinig a number value you can use `insert summary` option

Comment: No the summary isn't shown because as I explained that I am doing the SUM for a formula which has an if statement

Answer (score 0):

I have made function funsumColumn(dtfunSum, "intProductId", "decCBMCMS")
and pass datattable, table id name, and column name that i want to sum to.

This function returns sum of unique id row.

```
Private Function funsumColumn(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal idColumnName As String, ByVal ColumnForSum As String) As Decimal

    Dim dtnew As New DataTable
    dtnew.Columns.Add(idColumnName, GetType(Integer))
    dtnew.Columns.Add(ColumnForSum, GetType(Double))
    Dim dtMainTable As DataTable
    Dim ComputeColumnSum As Decimal
    Try
        Dim ExistIdInLocalTable As Integer
        Dim foundRow() As DataRow
        Dim PIid As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            PIid = dt.Rows(i).Item(idColumnName)
            foundRow = dtnew.Select("" & idColumnName & "='" & PIid & "'")
            ExistIdInLocalTable = foundRow.Count
            If foundRow.Count = 0 Then
                dtnew.Rows.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(idColumnName), dt.Rows(i).Item(ColumnForSum))
            Else
            End If
        Next
        dtMainTable = dtnew
        ComputeColumnSum = dtMainTable.Compute("sum(" & ColumnForSum & ")", "")
        Return ComputeColumnSum
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return ComputeColumnSum
```